# "Tolerably + *adjective*"

Tags: meaning

Does e.g. "[tolerably disgusting](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&es_sm=122&q=%22tolerably%20disgusting%22&oq=%22tolerably%20disgusting%22&gs_l=serp.3...6701.6701.0.7036.1.1.0.0.0.0.188.188.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.51.serp..1.0.0.22BTpGg-sfk)" mean the degree of disgust involved is tolerable or intolerable? Or "[tolerably vile](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&es_sm=122&q=%22tolerably%20vile%22&oq=%22tolerably%20vile%22&gs_l=serp.3...13790.14227.0.14394.4.4.0.0.0.0.188.188.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.51.serp..4.0.0.CgiY7znPArw)" - does it mean the vileness involved is tolerable or intolerable?

Comment: It simply means it is tolerable, and, it is disgusting. It's that simple.  **It is NOT one of those weird English things such as 'quite bad' or 'horribly good'**.  It is **NOT** one of those - it simply means the two words. (Like if I said "big red" or "cheap cheerful".)

Answer (score 3):

[Tolerably](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tolerably): adv.

> - in an acceptable (but not outstanding) manner; "she plays tennis tolerably"
> - acceptably, so-so

It means to an acceptable extent. The extent to which disgust or vileness are acceptable is a matter of personal  opinion.

Answer (score 3):

*Tolerably disgusting* means that the speaker finds it (whatever "it" is) disgusting, but can live with the level of disgust involved.

Similarly with *tolerably vile*: it's vile, but tolerable.

When something is "intolerably disgusting" it indicates that the speaker cannot stand the situation because of the disgust.

Generally, if something is described as *tolerable,* that's what it is.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that there are so few examples on the internet for either of these usages shows that you're probably better avoiding them yourself. Though not ungrammatical, they're far from *idiomatic* (considered normal by native speakers).

'Tolerably' is almost always used in the (downtoner) sense 'reasonably' when modifying an adverb or adjective, as [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/tolerably) indicates. And you'd not say 'reasonably disgusting' very often. The word is rarely if ever used with (especially strongly) 'negative' adjectives. This is not the case for 'intolerably', as Andrew indicates.

Answer (score 1):

A "tolerably good meal" means that the meal was all-right, but not splendid. But you are perhaps more likely to hear it as a somewhat ironic understatement, when you really mean "a very good meal indeed". "Tolerably disgusting" is something I would only say if I am trying to be funny. The humourous tone comes from the fact that it is an oxymoron: if something is disgusting then it is by definition not tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it means 'tolerably disgusting', such as picking your nose in a side street. But if you were doing it whilst walking along Piccadilly it would doubtless be considered 'intolerably disgusting'.